# How could i return a list of dictionaries with dbus?

Tags: python, dbus

I want return from a dbus daemon something like this:

```
>>> rule = {'name': 'torrent', 'port': '5892'}
>>> rule2 = {'name': 'amule', 'port': '234'}
>>> rules = []
>>> rules.append(rule)
>>> rules.append(rule2)
>>> rules
[{'name': 'torrent', 'port': '5892'}, {'name': 'amule', 'port': '234'}]
```

I'm trying this:

```
out_signature='a{ss}'
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict
```

Which out_signature have I to use?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this: out_signature='aa{ss}'
Cheers!